# RiverGIS under QGIS - Not able to execute "Extracting Manning's n values for cross-sections"

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, qgis-plugins

I am using RiverGIS plugin in QGIS and facing a problem in Extracting Manning's n values for cross-sections. The error code is as follow: -

Extracting Manning's n values for cross-sections
UndefinedFunction('function st_line_interpolate_point(geometry, numeric) does not exist\nLINE 39:         ST_Line_Interpolate_Point(inter_xs_dump.geom, 0.0000...\n                 ^\nHINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.\n')
Process aborted!

I am not very expert in in coding, so please help me.

Answer (score 3):

The error is apparently due to a change in the function name in PostGIS (several versions back...). If you're willing to do a trivial edit to one of the plugin python files, I think you'll be able to overcome this.

Find the plugin directory on your system, and open the file `hecobjects.py` with a simple text editor.
At line 839, change the function name `ST_Line_Interpolate_Point` to: `ST_LineInterpolatePoint`. (Remove two underscores. No other changes)

Save and then retry the plugin.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I tried this tip.
The plugin directory may be something like

> C:\Users\User_Name\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\rivergis

I changed `ST_Line_Interpolate_Point` into `ST_LineInterpolatePoint` in `hecobjects.py`.
Didn't work better.
Then I encountered `hecobjects.cpython-39.pyc`. Don't know a damn about this file, its language and what it is for, but it has the same function `ST_Line_Interpolate_Point`. I changed it into `ST_LineInterpolatePoint`, got no results.
Then I shut off QGIS and opened it again : yeeeh, it's ok !